# Can't connect to django application running on AWS Ubuntu EC2

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am runnig my Django application on AWS EC2 t2.micro with Ubuntu. I've successfuly installed all modules, created a PostgreSQL database, and made all migrations. Now when I'm running `python manage.py runserver 172.31.27.208:8000` I can't connect to it in browser, getting ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT error.

`python manage.py runserver 172.31.27.208:8000` returns:

```
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
January 30, 2020 - 11:10:59
Django version 3.0.2, using settings 'project_test.settings'
Starting development server at http://172.31.27.208:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
```

So I assume the server running properly.

I am using private ip form ec2 console which, I've checked, is matching to the ip adress returning by running command `ifconfig`.

TCP port is opened in AWS security_group inbound rules on port 8000.

I've also checked `netstat -lan` after running django server, it shows:

`tcp        0      0 172.31.27.208:8000      0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN`

I have been looking for same issues and everything listed in them seems to be correct in my case. Since that I have no idea what is going wrong. Can provide more information if you need something. Will appriciate any help. Thank you.

Comment: `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000` then go to the ip:8000 in browser

Comment: @Exprator, already tried this, doesn't connet as well.

Comment: is your 8000 port open in ec2 security group?

Comment: TCP port is opened in AWS security_group inbound rules on port 8000. Yes, @Lag11

Comment: @Exprator, thanks for the idea with ports, actually, I thought that tcp rule http 80 means that it is open on any port like 80xx, but it is not, I've added a custom TCP rule for port 8000, and now when I do runserver on private_ip:8000, it forwards properly and is avalible in the browser by public_ip:8000.

Comment: Thanks for help, everybody!